# Spring's Class Cast exception error on spring

Tags: java, spring, error-handling, spring-integration, classcastexception

I am new to Java Spring Framework, and for some reason when I try to run this class I get a ClassCastException error.
the three files of spring/main method, the secondary class and the Beans.xml screenshots are below. what am I doing wrong?

[image: HelloSpring Class]
[image: HelloWorld Class]
[image: Beans.xml File]
[image: Class Cast Exception error]

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots code add the code itself in the post it will be easy for others to test the code and you will get answer quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bean declaration in the xml is wrong. it must be:

```
<bean id="helloWorld" class="spring.test.HelloWorld"/>
                                              ^^^^^^
```

`HelloSpring` is your main class. `HelloWorld`is your bean class.

Comment: thanks, your way works with ApplicationContext and not BeanFactory.